# Animating ImageViews with delay

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewanimation

Learning Swift and ran into this today:

I have 3 images which I created outlets for:

```
@IBOutlet weak var bookImageView: SpringImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var sketchImageView: SpringImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var xcodeImageView: SpringImageView!
```

When I click the button action `learnButtonDidTouch` I want them to animate:

`bookImageView` right away

`sketchImageView` 0,2 delay

`xcodeImageView` 0,2 delay

During my search I have only found code that uses `UIView.animationWithDuration` but I haven't gotten far enough to understand why I cannot use `.animationWithDuration` directly on my ImageViews. What is the alternative here? Can't find anything on using `.animate()` or `.animation` with duration so I am guessing that I have to use `.animationWithDuration` on a `UIView`. But how would I do that in this case?

This is the code for when I press the button:

```
@IBAction func learnButtonDidTouch(sender: AnyObject) {
    sketchImageView.animation = "pop"
    xcodeImageView.animation = "pop"
    bookImageView.animation = "pop"
    sketchImageView.animate()
    xcodeImageView.animate()
    bookImageView.animate()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`animateWithDuration` has a `completionHandler:`. In the completion handler of the first animation, perform the second animation; in the completion handler of the second animation, perform the third animation.

Moreover, `animateWithDuration` has a `delay` parameter, so you'll be able to delay the second and third animations easily.

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely use UIView.animateWithDuration. Below is some code for that.

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, delay: 0, options: nil, animations: { () -> Void in
    //bookImageView animation
}, completion:
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, delay: 0, options: nil, animations: { () -> Void in
    //sketchImageView animation
    }, completion:
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, delay: 0, options: nil, animations: { () -> Void in
            //xcodeImageView animation
        }, completion: nil )
    )
)
```